# Do cross-schema queries in views have a performance impact in Oracle?

Tags: performance, oracle, database-design, schema

Will moving views from one schema to another have any adverse effect on performance?

I have about 40 views in one schema. I want to create a new schema which will have all the correct permissions. Suppose TableA resides in schema A. So my view will be in schema A. So I would do simply `select * from TableA`. Now I move this view to schema B. Since the table is in schema A, I would need to do `select * from A.TableA`. Will this cross-schema query cause any performance issues?

Comment: I think this question requires some more detail to be meaningful.

Comment: If the user doesn't have the correct permissions on the new schema it'll have a pretty serious effect!

Comment: @DaveCosta: OP provided details in a comment, I've edited them in (and also `s/scheme/schema/g`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is not where you might start in a performance review.

the sql of the actual view is probably far more important than which schema you place it in.

**edit**:

where the view resides should not affect performance. (aside from how the schema is laid out across blocks and datafiles)

Comment: I am not sure if my point is coming across.  I have about 40 views in one scheme.  I want to create a new scheme which will have all the correct permissions.  The code will exeucte because we will test it. Suppose TableA resides in schemeA.  So my view will be in schemeA.  So I would do simply select * from TableA.  Now I move this view to SchemeB.  since the table is in SchemeA, I would need to do Select * FROM SchemeA.TableA.  Would this cause any performance issues?  As far as I know, the answer is no. Just wanted to confirm.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If it's not a materialized view, it should have very little effect on performance.